# aws s3 in boto3 - how to move from the last page by paginator

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to process s3 objects by the `get_paginator` for `list_objects_v2`.

Since the process stopped midway, I wanted to run the same process starting with the last page.

Is there any way to do it by using `StartingToken` attribute? or any other solution for it?

Thanks

Comment: If you are working with a large number of objects (tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands), you could consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to retrieve a daily listing of objects, rather than calling `list_objects_v2`.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein. I'll dig into that. but for now, I had to use logic to start from where it stopped